# How to open a Word file with spaces in the name in AHK v2?

Tags: autohotkey

### ***What I'm trying to do***

I want to open word to a specific file.

---

### ***The Issue***

The file name has spaces - Word is interpreting the spaces as separate files.

---

### ***What I have so far***

```
Run "C:\Program Files (x86)\Office\WINWORD.EXE \\networkDrive\Upgrading Oracle SQL Developer.docx"
```

It definitely opens Word, so that part works. But then it tries to open "Upgrading.docx", "Oracle.docx", etc. Treating every word between spaces as a different document.

---

### ***The Question***

How can I tell MS Word to open the filename as a whole, instead of treating every word like a different file?

---

### ***What I've Tried***

- The escape character ( ` ) in front of the spaces
- Moving the file name to a variable
- Adding single quotes around the file name

Answer (score 1):

The outermost quotes will mean that you're specifying a string, they don't mean anything else.
Then you can specify in order:

```
program to run  
argument 1
argument 2
...  
argument n
```

**These are all separated with a space**  , just like normal when launching a program from the command line.

Your code now will try to do the following:

- program to run: `C:\Program Files`
- argument 1: `(x86)\Office\WINWORD.EXE`
  <sub><sup>(AHK is actually smart enough to understand here that you mean a long path ending in .exe, so this argument is combined to the program name above)</sup></sub>
- argument 2: `\\networkDrive\Upgrading`
- argument 3: `Oracle`
- argument 4: `SQL`
- argument 5: `Developer.docx`

To use program names, or arguments, that have spaces, you have to quote them. Just like you'd normally do when running something from the command line.
To quote, you can either escape quotes inside your quoted string `` `" ``, or you can combine single `'` and double `"` quotes:

```
Run("`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Office\WINWORD.EXE`" `"\\networkDrive\Upgrading Oracle SQL Developer.docx`"")
;or
Run('"C:\Program Files (x86)\Office\WINWORD.EXE" "\\networkDrive\Upgrading Oracle SQL Developer.docx"')
```

But actually even better than that, is that if Word is associated with the `.docx` file extension (as it should be), you can just run the filename. Don't need to specify the program:

```
Run("`"\\networkDrive\Upgrading Oracle SQL Developer.docx`"")
;or
Run('"\\networkDrive\Upgrading Oracle SQL Developer.docx"')
```